# How to get jenkins pipeline test results into ReportPortal.io instance?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, reportportal

I have an automated Jenkins workflow that runs and tests a java project. I need to get all the data and results that are outputted by Jenkins into Report Portal (RP).

Initially, I was under the impression that you have to [install the ReportPortal.io Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/reportportal) to be able to [configure Jenkins to communicate with RP](https://github.com/reportportal/plugin-jenkins/issues/6#issuecomment-457841570).

However, it appears that [the plugin will eventually be deprecated](https://github.com/reportportal/plugin-jenkins/issues/5#issuecomment-472439358).
According to one of the RP devs, there are APIs that can be used, but investigating them on our RP server does not give very clear instructions on what every API does or if it is what is required to get test data from Jenkins to RP.

**How then do I get Jenkins to send all generated data to RP?**

I am very familiar with Jenkins, but I am extremely new to Report Portal.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

ReportPortal is intended for test execution results collection, not for jenkins logs gathering. 
In two words, you need to find reporting agent at their github organization which depends on your testing framework (e.g. junit, testng, jbehave) and integrate it into your project. 
Here is example for TestNG framework:
https://github.com/reportportal/example-java-TestNG/